# View with ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewmodel

I have one ViewModels which contain other ViewModels

```
public class AllProductsViewModel
{
    public ICollection<ProductSearchViewModel> ProductSearch { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductRentViewModel> ProductRent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductBuyViewModel> ProductBuy { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller is:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var listOfProductsBuy = db.ProductsBuy.Select(x => new ProductBuyViewModel
        {

            Id = x.Id,
            Title = x.Title,
            MasterImageUrl = x.Images.FirstOrDefault().Url,
            Price = x.Price,
            Values = x.Value,

        }).ToList();

        var listOfProductsRent = db.ProductsRent.Select(y => new ProductRentViewModel
            {
                Id = y.Id,
                Title = y.Title,
                MasterImageUrl = y.ImagesRent.FirstOrDefault().Url,
                Price = y.Price,
                Values = y.Value,
            }).ToList();

        var listOfProductsSearch = db.ProductSearches.Select(z => new ProductSearchViewModel
        {
            Id = z.Id,
            Title = z.Title,
            MasterImageUrl = z.ImagesSearch.FirstOrDefault().Url,
            Price = z.Price,
            Values = z.Value,
        }).ToList();

        var viewModel = new AllProductsViewModel { ProductBuy = listOfProductsBuy, ProductRent = listOfProductsRent, ProductSearch = listOfProductsSearch };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

And my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<RealEstateMarket.ViewModels.AllProductsViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<br />
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <h3>@item.ProductBuy.Select(x => x.Title)</h3>
                <div>
                    <img height="100" width="120" class="thumbnail" src="@item.ProductBuy.Select(x => x.MasterImageUrl )" />
                </div>
                <h3>@item.ProductBuy.Select(x => x.Price) @item.ProductBuy.Select(x => x.Values.Currency)</h3>
            }        
        </div>
</div>
```

A want to take the fields of ProductBuyViewModel,ProductRentViewModel, ProductSearchViewModel 
When I start this code i get the error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'RealEstateMarket.ViewModels.AllProductsViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RealEstateMarket.ViewModels.AllProductsViewModel]'.

Comment: try changing ienumerable to List

Comment: Your View is expecting multiple `AllProductsViewModel` as its model but you're only passing one `AllProductsViewModel` to it. You need to ask yourself *is* your view supposed to deal with multiple or just single `AllProductsViewModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
 @model IEnumerable<RealEstateMarket.ViewModels.AllProductsViewModel>
```

to

```
 @model RealEstateMarket.ViewModels.AllProductsViewModel
```

and then you can access to your list

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @for (int index=0;index<Model.ProductSearch.Count();index++)
        {
            <h3>@Model.ProductSearch[index].Title</h3>
            <div>
                <img height="100" width="120" class="thumbnail" src="@Model.ProductSearch[index].MasterImageUrl )" />
            </div>
            <h3>@Model.ProductSearch[index].Price @Model.ProductSearch[index].Values.Currency)</h3>
        }        
    </div>
```

Comment: If I change this then I can not use foreach with Model

Comment: i update the answer, and it will better if you use the normal "for"